# JSON serializer for Salesforce post callout

Tags: salesforce, jsonserializer

I want to serialize my data into following format. So that I can send in post call out from Salesforce to external API.

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "sample string 2",
    "LastName": "sample string 3",
    "Email": "sample string 4",
    "Phone": "sample string 5",
    "AddressId": 6,
    "Address": {
        "Id": 1,
        "Street1": "sample string 2",
        "Street2": "sample string 3",
        "StreetNo": "sample string 4",
        "Zip": "sample string 5",
        "City": "sample string 6",
        "StateId": 7,
        "State": {
            "StateId": 1,
            "Code": "sample string 2",
            "Name": "sample string 3",
            "CreatedDate": "2018-07-18T11:29:57.0831407+05:30",
            "ModfiedDate": "2018-07-18T11:29:57.0831407+05:30"
        },
        "Phone": "sample string 8",
        "Email": "sample string 9",
        "WebsiteLink": "sample string 10",
        "CountryId": 11,
    }
```

I am trying the following code. I need address as one object inside the whole object:

```
Address addr=new Address();
addr.Phone='8943023308';
addr.Street1='doddakanali';
addr.Street2='a144F000000Cvit';
addr.Zip=894309;
addr.City='calicut';
addr.StateId=1;
addr.CountryId=1;

JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);    
gen.writeStartObject();      
gen.writeNumberField('Id ',0);
gen.writeStringField('FirstName','leo');
gen.writeStringField('LastName','messi');
gen.writeStringField('Email','leo2016@gmail.com');
gen.writeNumberField('CompnayId ',1);             
gen.writeObjectField('Address',addr);
gen.writeEndObject();

String jsonS = gen.getAsString(); 
System.debug('jsonMaterials'+jsonS);
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to:

1., Create a new Apex class:

```
public class MyDataStructure {

    public Address Address      ;
    public Decimal Id           ;
    public String FirstName     ;
    public String LastName      ;
    public String Email         ;
    public String Phone         ;
    public Decimal AddressId    ;

    public class Address {
        public State   State          ;    
        public Decimal Id             ;
        public String  Street1        ;     
        public String  Street2        ;     
        public String  StreetNo       ;      
        public String  Zip            ; 
        public String  City           ;  
        public Decimal StateId        ;     
        public String  Phone          ;   
        public String  Email          ;   
        public String  WebsiteLink    ;         
        public Decimal CountryId      ;       
    }

    public class State {
            public Decimal StateId        ;
            public String  Code           ;
            public String  Name           ;
            public String  CreatedDate    ;
            public String  ModfiedDate    ;
    }

}
```

2., Construct the class(es), assign values, and use the `JSON.serialize()` method to generate the sting:

```
MyDataStructure mds = new MyDataStructure();
mds.Id        = 1                  ;
mds.FirstName = 'sample string 2'  ;
mds.LastName  = 'sample string 3'  ;
mds.Email     = 'sample string 4'  ;
mds.Phone     = 'sample string 5'  ;
mds.AddressId = 6                  ;

mds.Address             = new MyDataStructure.Address();
mds.Address.Id          = 1                  ;
mds.Address.Street1     = 'sample string 2'  ;
mds.Address.Street2     = 'sample string 3'  ;
mds.Address.StreetNo    = 'sample string 4'  ;
mds.Address.Zip         = 'sample string 5'  ;
mds.Address.City        = 'sample string 6'  ;
mds.Address.StateId     = 7                  ;
mds.Address.Phone       = 'sample string 8'  ;
mds.Address.Email       = 'sample string 9'  ;
mds.Address.WebsiteLink = 'sample string 10' ;
mds.Address.CountryId   = 11                 ;

mds.Address.State = new MyDataStructure.State();
mds.Address.State.StateId     = 1                                   ;
mds.Address.State.Code        = 'sample string 2'                   ;
mds.Address.State.Name        = 'sample string 3'                   ;
mds.Address.State.CreatedDate = '2018-07-18T11:29:57.0831407+05:30' ;
mds.Address.State.ModfiedDate = '2018-07-18T11:29:57.0831407+05:30' ;


System.debug( JSON.serialize( mds ) );
```

Comment: thank you @martin .the effort you put to show how it has to be is really appreciable.
its really working for me